# how can spring data neo4j NodeEntity annotation with multible Label?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have tried a single label in neo4j. A Node can have multiply Labels in database. How can I implement it in Spring-Data?

Comment: please share some code that you tried out on ur own.

Comment: How to implement multiply label with annotation in spring-data-neo4j? `CREATE (m:Movie:Cinema:Film:Picture)`

Comment: please update ur question with appropriate amounts of code/ references that you have tried so that we can help u better.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [inheritance](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity) (I) (first code and cypher sample in the paragraph)  or provide a field in your class with the `@Labels` (II) [annotation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity:runtime-managed-labels).

Short samples:

I)

```
@NodeEntity
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {}
```

will create a node labeled with `MyEntity` and `BaseEntity`.

II)

```
@Labels
private List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
```

the labels have to be of the type `List<String>`. Every entry in this list will be used when persisting the entity.